# Date time C# get a 10 day cycle working have the exceptions (weekends and holidays)

Tags: c#, datetime, cycle

im 13 and i'm creating a program  visual c# that would tell the user what class they have in the specific day of the cycle and period for example on day 1 period 1 you would have math ect
could someone help me with the code that would do this 
"add 1 to an integer everyday except for saturday,sunday and holidays.every 10 days start from 0"
i'm sure its simple but i'm a beginner who started a year ago. any help would be greatly appreciated
if i didn't explain what i want clearly please say so and i clarify it

Thank You,

Manitha

Comment: You have to ask a specific question.  Have you looked at the DateTime documentation on MSDN?  Have you tried anything yet?  Did you get stuck?

Comment: You may have missed the "How to ask" page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask your question is likely to be closed or downvoted because you are asking for code without having showed what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following resources will help you:

The `while` or `for` loop constructs (to loop over your days and periods): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

The `continue` keyword (to skip days you don't want to process): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx

The `DateTime` documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Specifically, the `DayOfWeek` property (to find out what day you are currently looking at in order to skip over it): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

And the `AddDays` method (to get to the next day): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx

I don't believe what you actually want (maybe it is what you want but working with the correct data type for a problem is often half the battle of finding a solution, and if there's anything I've learned it is that there is almost always a better solution) is to just add one to an integer, which is why I have included the documentation for the `DateTime` structure.

If you really need an integer representation, consider the text in the remarks section of the `DayOfWeek` documentation page, specifically the following:

> If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

Comment: The question may simply be asking for code as a quick fix, instead of simply replying with a functional code sample that could be copy and pasted, I am trying to encourage the OP to think for themselves. If that is grounds for a downvote, so be it =]

I fully expect this question to be closed before long but if I have helped one young programmer with a problem and encouraged them to think for themselves a little bit more, I'm happy =]